# What are potential risks of creating generic array with varargs in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, variadic-functions

I found a way to create generic array inline with varargs and anonymous inner class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GenericArrayCreate<C> {

   public void method() {

      C[] ans = new Object() { C[] c(int length, C ... cs) { return Arrays.copyOf(cs, length); }}.c(10);

      System.out.println(ans.length);
      System.out.println(Objects.toString(ans));

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new GenericArrayCreate<Class<? extends Integer>>().method();
   }
}
```

<s>Java compiler produces no any warning on this code, while</s> code inspection (in IntelliJ) says:

```
Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter
```

What is happening here and why is it swearing?

Answer (score 3):

Internally you are creating an array of "Object" instead of a array of "C"

Try this code :

```
 public static <C>  C[]  method(int number) {
   return  new Object() { 
     C[] create(int length, C ... cs) {
       return Arrays.copyOf(cs, length); 
     }
   }.create(number);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(Main.<Integer>method(10));
   System.out.println(new Integer[10]);
 }
```

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@6bc7c054
>
> [Ljava.lang.Integer;@232204a1

As you can see they are not the same.

It is dangerous because if you run something like these:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Integer[] integerArray1 = Main.<Integer>method(10);
   Integer[] integerArray2 = new Integer[10];
 }
```

And you will have a ClassCastException

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer

If you want to create any kind of array you need to send the class to construct the array, you can do it like this:

```
public static <C>  C[]  method(Class<C> clazz, int number) {
  return  (C[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, number);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer[] integerArray1 = Main.<Integer>method(Integer.class, 10);
  Integer[] integerArray2 = new Integer[10];
}
```

Comment: @Dims any comment about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Code inspection will note that because varargs are implemented with array, and array do not support generics. But you can suppress that warning by adding this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Reason why this happens is it can lead to loss of information. You can read more about that [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ300).